# HTTP response following long process

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets

The current project is in Node.js with the Expressjs framework. We have an application with client/prospect information, authenticated users are allowed to modify the database and initiate long-running processes on the server. As an example, printing a 30 pg document could be one process.

The application user needs two main things:

1. A response when the process begins.
2. A response (notification) when the process ends.

We currently handle need #1 in standard express fashion by ensuring the process starts followed by `res.json({msg: 'Process Started']);` back to the Angular front end. Need #2 is currently handed with an email to the user that initiated the process with a process status report.

I would like to improve how we handle need #2. Specifically, I would like to send a JSON string to the user to display in the interface.

**Questions**:

1. Is it possible to do this over HTTP?
2. Does this functionality exist within Express or a well-know middleware.

Assuming 1 & 2 are false. My solution is to run a TCP socket server to maintain a socket with the required users. When a process ends a message is sent to the user with a status update. Can anyone comment on the issues my solution presents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Yes* to both 1 and 2. Essentially what you seek to achieve here is to push from the server to the client. The need to do this is pretty ubiquitous in web applications and there have been various solutions for it over the years with various fancy names. You might like to read up on `Ajax`, `Comet`, `Long-polling`, `Websockets`.

For your node application, take a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io). In a nutshell, what this framework does is it abstracts the complexities of Ajax, Websockets, etc. into a single API. Put another way, socket.io gives you bi-directional communications between your node application and front end.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have been more clear and asked if there was a way to do this without `Websockets` or `Long-Polling`. It looks like I may be able to achieve this with an XMLHttpRequest and utilizing `onreadystatechange`. If `Websockets` are the preferred approach then I either need to write my own `net` server or implement `socket.io`.

Comment: As you're using Node at your server and using an Angular front end, what's the reason for not wanting to simply throw in the `socket.io` library? Is the reason because you also want a desktop application or similar to talk to the node service?

Comment: I was looking for something lighter. It looks like Angular has scraped `onreadystatechage` from `$http` services so while not out-of-the-question, it is depreciated. I will give socket.io another look as a solution, it provides much more than I need though, which is a simple queue of status that get flushed to the user on completion. Cheers

Comment: If you really did want to keep with plain HTTP for some reason (as opposed to using socket.io which AFAIK uses the 'best available', using Websockets is available but falling back to plain HTTP methods - don't quote me on that but that's what I assume it does) then you're limited to polling (frequent HTTP requests) or long-polling. In fact, long-polling is the technique I'm using right now for an embedded C application to talk to a node server.